# How to timeout ADB connect <ip>

Tags: networking, shell, android, adb

I'm making automation bash script that will go over range of IP's and try to connect over ADB.

If I try:

```
adb connect <not android device>
```

the command will hang for 30 seconds until it say

```
"failed to connect to '192.168.1.231:5555': Operation timed out".
```

How I can make ADB connect to try to connect for less time. Something like 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
timeout <seconds> adb connect <ip-address>
```

More can be found on: https://linuxize.com/post/timeout-command-in-linux/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).